# Why aren't my emitter particles appearing in the render? 2.8

Tags: rendering, particles

I am trying to make rain in my scene and I have created 2 particle systems for this, one that is the rain falling from the sky being emitted out of a circle and the other is the splashes from the ground. The ground is working fine but the particles from the sky aren't appearing in the render. I have the render button on in the outliner and I can't figure out what's going wrong.[image][image]

[image]

Comment: does the original drop render? (can you share the blender file?)

Comment: Sorry, how do you do that? :D

Comment: upload the blender file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and share the link, so we can inspect your scene.

Comment: Thank's, there you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some fixes:

- goto the raindrop object properties > Instancing > switch to None
- go to the emitter, clear the bake cache and recalculate the bake
- just to check that drops now are in the render: go to shader and
  make the drop more visible (for example make the shader less transparent)

result:
[image]